# Best way to load delimited file to oracle database from a feed directory

Tags: oracle, csv

I have a directory that will populated daily by delimited file feeds. I want an automated procedure to read and load these file data to oracle database. Problem is these files are named by mmddyyyyhhmmss.csv format

In simple way: Monday = 001.csv, 002.csv, 003.csv 
so Monday evening a batch job will run sqlplus procedure and load these files to db.

Tuesday = 004.csv, 005.csv.
Tuesday evening plsql will be run by a batch job and load these files.

Wednesday ...... and so on.

Please let me know what is the best way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Consider SQL loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CSV files are named with a date/timestamp then the trick is determining which files to load.

I'd recommend you're preferred programming language (Python, Perl, Java....) that can get the list of filenames in a directory. If the directory can be seen by the database server, you can use external tables. I'd suggest using renaming the 'current' file to where ever the external table points, loading it in, then renaming the file back

Comment: Thanks Gary, I was able to achieve the solution using Java Stored Procedure. What it does is get the list of files inside the folder and loop through each then load and archive.